# How do you add space between characters except for a word?

Tags: python, regex, text

I have a string:

```
string = "abc(word)def(word)oiu"
```

I need the output as:

```
spaced = "a b c (word) d e f (word) o i u"
```

Comment: And what have you tried?  You either need to do a character at a time, or use `split` and process the pieces.

Comment: I have tried " ".join(string) but that puts a space between all characters. I am looking to have space between except the string (word)

Comment: What I mean is `x.split("(word)")`, then expand the parts, the rejoin them.

Comment: except a word, or except anything within brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `re.sub`:

```
s = "abc(word)def(word)oiu"
re.sub("\(.+?\)", lambda x: x.group(0).replace(" ", ""), " ".join(s))
```

Output:

```
'a b c (word) d e f (word) o i u'
```

This will first put spaces in between all characters, and remove spaces that are between brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple and avoid regex trickery for a basic situation
like this:

```
s = "abc(word)def(word)oiu"
w = '(word)'

spaced_out = f' {w} '.join(' '.join(text) for text in s.split(w))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pattern `'\(.+?\)|.'` to separate the input into substrings that should be joined by spaces, and then use `' '.join()` to insert those spaces.

We look for a `(`, followed by one or more characters, followed by a `)`. We use `?` so that we stop at the next closing parenthesis we see, rather than the last `)` in the string. If we can't match that pattern, we just take the next character:

```py
import re
data = "abc(word)def(word)oiu"
result = ' '.join(re.findall(r'\(.+?\)|.', data))
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```py
a b c (word) d e f (word) o i u
```

Answer (score 0):

This can work for any given string.

```
string = "abc(word)def(word)oiu"
skip_word= "(word)"     
spaced_string = " ".join([char for char in string])
spaced_word =  " ".join([char for char in skip_word])

spaced = spaced_string.replace(spaced_word, skip_word)
```